# Surpress notification for google documents permission additions when using API

Tags: google-api, google-docs-api, email-notifications

I am trying to surpress the email notification for permission additions to google documents when using the api.  For example, using the API, I create a new document and add another viewer of the document.  Currently that other viewer receives an email from google notifying him of this document.

I would like to surpress the email via the API.

I can see [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#email_notifications_of_acl_changes) that there is a way to do this using the send-notification-emails flag on **update** of the acl but not on create.  I have tried to use the flag on create and as expected it doesn't do anything.  Is there another way to surpress the notification on create?

Comment: If you have a reproducible case, perhaps follow up w/ original google ticket:

Perhaps follow up on original ticket

http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2382

Comment: What do you mean by Creating an ACL? I have not used this API so I have no first-hand experience in this; but from a quick look at the documentation that you provided link for, what I understand is that you do not create an ACL, you create a document and it has an ACL that lists you as the owner. Then, when you want to add the other user whom you do not want to send e-mails, what you do is to UPDATE the ACL. You add the parameter to this request and the other user never gets an e-mail about his being added to this document as viewer.

Comment: I "think" I'm reading it correctly, right??.  Here is the applicable text: "Creating an ACL entry that shares a document or collection with users will by default notify relevant users via email that they have new access to the document or collection.  However, these emails can be disabled by attaching the send-notification-emails parameter to ACL URIs when modifying an ACL.".  To me this is saying (and in my testing I have proved this) that if you are adding someone via creating ACL then they will always get notified, but on an update of their ACL you have the option.

Comment: Text says you create an ACL *entry* not ACL. ACL (Access Control List) have only you as the owner when you *create the document* but once the document is created, then you can update the ACL by adding others to it with different roles. So, it says when you add the new viewer to document, i.e when you are updating the ACL of document, you can use this parameter. In the history of implementation, there was a bug that prevented this parameter to be ignored. If you are adding this parameter but it still sends the notification, bug has apparently reappeared!

Comment: I think it must be broken again....here's the URL I'm using:  https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/document%3A[left out actual document id]/acl?send-notification-emails=false

Answer (score 1):

OK - user error.  Actually it was deep in the ruby gem we were using where it was chopping off the params in a URL.  I had to pass in the params differently than just on the URL after the "?".  For those who stumble upon this test using Fiddler or Wireshark to make sure your params are being kept in the POST.

Answer (score 0):

Read of someone having similar issues in a python interface into GDocs. They were just adding "?send-notification-emails=false" to the request, not realizing it already had a "?". So, they ended up having to test for "?" in the current url and use "&" if exists.